# value_counts top 20 records

Tags: pandas, count, header, frequency

I have a dataset with 500 rows × 9 columns. I'm trying to create a value counts function of my top 20 revenue sales.

Here is an example of my rows

|Store_Number |Region |Address |City |State| Zip |Revenue |Loses|

This is the code I'm using

```
df_file_name.Revenue.value_counts().to_frame()
```

the output only gives me the top 5 revenue and the bottom 5 revenue. I need a code to output the top 20.

Comment: `df_file_name.Revenue.value_counts().head(20)`.

Comment: I tried that but it did not retrieve my top 20.  I have a list of 6213 records and I need to see data for the top 20. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I do value_counts I get the top 5 and the bottom  5.

Comment: I was able to move the cell up and it worked.  Thank you. It give me a list of my top 20. How do get it to load as a nice data frame?

Comment: Chain that with `.reset_index()`

Comment: I was able to get it running.     df_file_name.Revenue.value_counts().head(20).frame